# Error in VBA Excel-SQL coding as "User Defined Type Not Defined" for "Recordset"

Tags: sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008, excel

I am relatively experienced in VBA coding, but I am totally new in MS SQL server 2008.

I am trying to export an Excel table like below to a SQL server:

```
    A    B    C   D    E
1 Name  Year  ID 
2 Jill  2015  17
3 Jack  2012  13
4 Mike  1999  25
5
```

After activating ADO and DAO in the tools, it fixed the error "User Defined Type Not Defined" for the line `Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset`. But now I get an error for the line `Set dbclass = New clsDB`. I don't understand what is wrong. The same definition structure works in another Workbook.

```
Private Sub Transtable()

Dim connOk As Boolean
Dim MyWorkBook As Workbook
Dim CurSheet As Worksheet
Dim listObj As ListObject
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
' Dim dbclass As New clsDB  ' both description leads to the same "User Undefined" error
' Dim dbclass As New ADODB.clsDB 
Set dbclass = New clsDB

dbclass.Database = "Tables"
dbclass.ConnectionType = SqlServer
dbclass.DataSource = "E72b1783"
dbclass.UserId = Application.UserName

  connOk = dbclass.OpenConnection(False, True)

  If connOk = False Then
     MsgBox "Connection not successfull"

  Else
     MsgBox "Connection successfull"
  End If

  tableName = "TableName1"
  Set CurSheet = Sheet2
  Set listObj = CurSheet.ListObjects(tableName) 'Table Name

  'get range of Table
  HeaderRange = listObj.HeaderRowRange.Address
  DataRange = listObj.DataBodyRange.Address

  dbclass.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & ws.Name & "$" & Replace(DataRange, "$", "") & "];"
   rs.Open strSQL, dbclass, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

   arrData = rs.GetRows

   rs.Close
   dbclass.Close
   Set rs = Nothing
   Set dbclass = Nothing
   Set listObj = Nothing
   Set CurSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Stupid question, but I assume that you have set a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access 2010 compile error User-defined type not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889833/access-2010-compile-error-user-defined-type-not-defined)

Comment: @Tom it is not stupid question at all. As I wrote at the beginning, I am totally new in SQL connections, and I didn't get any similar error in VBA before.

ADO and DAO solved the problem for the line `Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset`, but now I get the same error for the line `Set dbclass = New clsDB` which describes the connection. I even added a new line like  `Dim dbclass As New ADODB.Connection`, but it keeps the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['User Defined Type Not Defined' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261557/user-defined-type-not-defined-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Data Access Objects library (DAO) is checked in the Tools. Also look at the ActiveX Data Objects library (**ADO**) in the list. References list in the VBA Editor's menu/ribbon. (The specific name of the library can be different in different versions of Access)

Comment: Thanks. I activated the both DAO and ADO now. It solved the problem for the `Recordset`, but now I get the same error for the line `Set dbclass = New clsDB` which describes the SQL-connection.

I even added extra line like `Dim dbclass As New Connection`, but it gives the same "User Defined Type Not Defined" error.

Comment: It should not be `Dim dbclass As New Connection` instead it should be `Dim dbclass As New ADODB.Connection`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote here "without" copy-paste, so I wrote here wrong. I already wrote as  `Dim dbclass As New ADODB.Connection`. 

But another guy wrote the same code without `Dim dbclass`, and his code works without error.

Comment: :D you can ask the another guy what he wrote. but I believe you can write `Dim dbclass As New ADODB.Connection` and after that `Set dbclass = New ADODB.Connection`

Comment: Can u update your question and show what is ur clsDB looks like

Comment: Actually I am not completely sure about using clsDB now (I took `clsDB` description from a guy, and I took the description for copying a table from another guy).

Can you show an alternative method to build up my connection instead of `clsDB`

Comment: I think I was supposed to write `Dim dbclass As New clsDB`, but it gave the same `User Defined Type` error.

Comment: @user3714330: This is completly a new question. Please Ask another question for it. And since it solves your issue accept it as answer. You can notify me about your another question here itself. I'll try to solve it sooner

Comment: Now I have asked another question in similar topic: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182587/error-in-vba-excel-sql-coding-as-application-defined-or-object-defined-error)