# Updating Invoice Data to Access Database with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a **Sheet1(BILL FORMAT)** in excel to save my records in a sheets like **sheet3(ITEM DATA)**. But after few days working with this **Sheet1(BILL FORMAT)**, it is now goes slower, because of heavy data saving in **sheet3(ITEM DATA)**. Now I want to save all records to a **Access database** and want to keep clean my **sheet3(ITEM DATA)**. So I can work on my **Sheet1(BILL FORMAT)** easily or without any delay. Also wants updates my record by calling it via serial numbers. but I don't want to keep any record in my **sheet3(ITEM DATA)**.

[image: BILL FORMAT SHEET]

[image: DATA STORED SHEET]

Given below link is good for **save invoice records**. Because its saves records one by one row.
[PREVIOUS RELATED LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238939/how-to-transfer-vba-userform-data-to-access-database)

But now i also required save **invoice Items Records.**

My Little Code is mentioned below: -

```
    Sub SAVE_DATA()
  i = 1
  Do Until Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("BILL FORMAT").Range("B1").Value Then
      'Ask overwrite invoice #?
      'If MsgBox("Overwrite invoice data?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
      Else
        Exit Do
      'End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  i = 1
  Set rng_dest = Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("G:K")
  'Delete rows if invoice # is found
  Do Until Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = ""
    If Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("BILL FORMAT").Range("B1").Value Then
      Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
      i = 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop

    Set rng_dest = Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("G:K")
  ' Find first empty row in columns G:K on sheet ITEM DATA
  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  'Copy range A7:E11 on sheet BILL FORMAT to Variant array
  Set Rng = Sheets("BILL FORMAT").Range("A7:E11")

  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet ITEM DATA
  For a = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = Rng.Rows(a).Value

      'Copy SR. NO.
      Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("BILL FORMAT").Range("B1").Value
      
      'Copy NAME
      Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("D" & i).Value = Sheets("BILL FORMAT").Range("B2").Value
      
      'Copy LOCATION
      Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("E" & i).Value = Sheets("BILL FORMAT").Range("B3").Value
      
      'Copy CONTACT
      Sheets("ITEM DATA").Range("F" & i).Value = Sheets("BILL FORMAT").Range("B4").Value

      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheet3.Columns("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value + 1
Range("B2:B4").ClearContents
Range("A7:D11").ClearContents

Range("B2").Select

End Sub
```

and i have no idea how to convert this sheet code to link with access database.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve records from the database back onto the sheet to update them ? How many lines on the sheet after a few days when you notice it slowing down ? When deleting rows it is better to work up the sheet, you seem to be repetitively scanning down the sheet on every delete.

Comment: Thank You for your kind reply. **1)**- Actually sir, retrieve data from database is a another question. and I will ask that question later.  **2)**- After working on this sheet (BILL FORMAT) for 2 to 3 months, about 3000 or 4000 rows are saved in (ITEM DATA SHEET), which makes it difficult to work later. So now I want to save all data to a access database. and want to my ITEM DATA SHEET clean. So if my Excel workbook today is 50 kb, then after a month or even after 10 months this workbook should remain 50 kb. And all item records must be saved in the access database.

Comment: What triggers the save and sheet clearance.? How do you want to resolve conflicts between the spreadsheet and the database For example where a ser. no. on the sheet already exists in the database?  You need to describe your access database [schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema), the table names , the field names, the field types and any constraint like primary keys.

Comment: DataBase Name **testDB.accdb**, Table Name **MyTable** , Fields names are following (SR. NO., NAME, LOCATION, CONTACT, DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, UNIT TYPE, RATE, TOTAL). Actually it is similar to this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238939/how-to-transfer-vba-userform-data-to-access-database).

Comment: Sir There is a little mistake. First Field Name is "**Sr**" not "**SR. NO.**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed fieldname "NAME" to COMPANY as NAME is a reserved word

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveToDB()

    Const DBNAME = "testDB.accdb"
    Const COL_SR = "C"

    Dim sCon As String, oCon As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sPath As String, SQL As String, sFields As String, t0 As Single
    t0 = Timer

    ' build SQL
    sFields = Join(Array("SR", "COMPANY", "LOCATION", "CONTACT", _
                         "DESCRIPTION", "QUANTITY", "UNIT_TYPE", _
                         "RATE", "TOTAL"), ",")

    SQL = " INSERT INTO MyTable (" & sFields & _
          ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" ' 9 fields
    
    'Debug.Print SQL
   
    ' open connection to database
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sPath & DBNAME & ";"
  
    Set oCon = New ADODB.Connection
    oCon.Open sCon

    ' command with parameters
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = oCon
        .CommandText = SQL
        .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, 1, 255) ' SR
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adVarChar, 1, 255) ' COMPANY
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P3", adVarChar, 1, 255) ' LOCATION
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P4", adVarChar, 1, 255) ' CONTACT
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P5", adVarChar, 1, 255) ' DESCRIPTION
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P6", adNumeric, 1) ' QUANTITY
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P7", adVarChar, 1, 255) ' UNIT_TYPE
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P8", adNumeric, 1) ' RATE
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P9", adNumeric, 1) ' TOTAL
    End With
    
    ' scan sheet for records to insert
    Dim wb As Workbook, wsItem As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsItem = wb.Sheets("ITEM DATA")
    iLastRow = wsItem.Cells(Rows.count, COL_SR).End(xlUp).Row
    'Debug.Print iLastRow

    If iLastRow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No records to insert", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' INSERT new recordz
    Dim col(8), n, i, iRow As Long, count As Long

    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow

        For i = 0 To 8
            col(i) = wsItem.Range("C2").Offset(iRow - 2, i).Value
        Next
        col(5) = CDec(col(5)) ' decimal
        col(7) = CDec(col(7))
        col(8) = CDec(col(8))
    
        ' execute INSERT rows affected, parameters
        cmd.Execute n, col
        count = count + n
    
    Next
    MsgBox count & " rows inserted into MyTable", vbInformation, Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"
    oCon.Close
 
    ' clear sheet
    wsItem.Range("C2:K" & iLastRow).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    wsItem.Range("C2:K" & iLastRow).Clear

End Sub
```

Your input sub re-written using [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) and [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.FindNext) to avoid repeated scans.

```vb
Sub SaveInvoice()

    Const COL_SRNO = "C"
    Const ROW_FIRST = "7" ' first item

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsBill As Worksheet, wsItem As Worksheet
    Dim SerNo As String, rng As Range, iLastItem As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim d As Long, i As Long, n As Long, msg As String, t0 As Single

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    t0 = Timer
    
    Set wsBill = wb.Sheets("BILL FORMAT")
    Set wsItem = wb.Sheets("ITEM DATA")
    iLastRow = wsItem.Cells(Rows.count, COL_SRNO).End(xlUp).Row
    'Debug.Print iLastRow

   ' search and delete any existing serno in column C
    SerNo = wsBill.Range("B1").Value
    If Len(SerNo) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Serial Number is blank", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    With wsItem.Range(COL_SRNO & "2:" & COL_SRNO & iLastRow)
        Set rng = .Find(What:=SerNo, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False)
        
        ' delete rows if found
        Do While Not rng Is Nothing
            'Debug.Print "Delete", rng.Address
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
            d = d + 1
            If d > iLastRow Then Exit Sub ' infinite loop protection

            Set rng = .FindPrevious
        Loop
    End With

    ' find next blank row
    iLastRow = wsItem.Cells(Rows.count, COL_SRNO).End(xlUp).Row

    ' last item
    iLastItem = wsBill.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     
    ' copy bill items
    n = ROW_FIRST
    For n = ROW_FIRST To iLastItem
        If Len(wsBill.Range("A" & n)) > 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            With wsItem.Cells(iLastRow + i, COL_SRNO)
                .Offset(0, 0) = Trim(wsBill.Range("B1")) ' SR NO
                .Offset(0, 1) = Trim(wsBill.Range("B2")) ' NAME
                .Offset(0, 2) = Trim(wsBill.Range("B3")) ' LOCATION
                .Offset(0, 3) = Trim(wsBill.Range("B4")) ' CONTACT
                .Offset(0, 4).Resize(1, 5) = wsBill.Range("A" & n).Resize(1, 5).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next

    ' result
    msg = d & " rows deleted " & vbCrLf & i & " rows inserted"
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, Int(Timer - t0) & " seconds"

    ' next serial no
    With wsBill
       .Activate
       .Range("B1").Value = .Range("B1").Value + 1
       '.Range("B2:B4").ClearContents
       '.Range("A7:D11").ClearContents
       .Activate
       .Range("B2").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Sir, No Doubt, You are my hero. Thank You very much. Some little changes required but now I will do it myself. Thank You very much.

Comment: Thank You Sir, This is working, but how to do this at one click without duplicate entry in database. Actually pop-up messages are irrelevant (I think This is not necessary). and I found QUANTY and RATE columns are same values in database.

Comment: @prabhat I have corrected the Quantity and Rate columns see update.

Comment: Thank You very much sir. You are really genius.